# Fitting wrap column in print composer of QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer

i have an attribute table in the map composer, and the field i want to see is quite long so i wrap it, but the field width is not fitting this new length.

Is QGIS 2.4 able to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not currently possible - attribute tables in print composer only support a single row of text. See http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10273 and http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8006

Answer (score 5):

As @ndawson said right now it is not possible, as a workaround I usually use the `wordwrap` function (you can find it in the expression engine) to wrap the text and I adjust it to fit by playing around the appearance groupbox like cell margins. I get as result something like this:

[image]

In my case I used `wordwrap("ERROR", 25)`, it adds a `\n` each 25 characters.